# Custom ClamAV signatures not working

Tags: clamav

I'm attempting to create some custom signatures for ClamAV for testing purposes. I create signatures like this:

```
sigtool --md5 test.exe > test.hdb
```

Next to test it I do:

```
clamscan -d test.hdb test.exe
```

Now it appears to load the database and scan the file, but I don't get any matched infection back:

```
/tmp/scan/test.exe: OK

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 1
Engine version: 0.102.4
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 1
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 58.59 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 0.002 sec (0 m 0 s)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the default scan sizes at fault. If I use `--max-filesize` and `--max-scansize` the scan completes.

Command:

```
clamscan -d test.hdb --max-filesize=100M --max-scansize=100M test.exe
```

Output:

```
/tmp/scan/test.exe: Test.Win32.VirusA.UNOFFICIAL FOUND

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 1
Engine version: 0.102.4
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 1
Infected files: 1
Data scanned: 58.61 MB
Data read: 58.59 MB (ratio 1.00:1)
Time: 0.747 sec (0 m 0 s)
```

Comment: I would be better if you had added the full command you ran to get this output.